# Should the ground state electron density of an atom go to zero at the origin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, atoms

I have heard from my professor that the particle density of electrons (in the ground state) of an atom should vanish near the nucleus. Hydrogen is an obvious counter-example. So I am trying to work out what he could have meant? Which quantum phenomenon is he thinking of?

Comment: I think that $s$ states of hydrogen demonstrate that your professor’s statement is false. I suggest that you ask him or her about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hydrogen is an obvious counter-example.

Indeed it is. The claim as stated is false.

> So I am trying to work out what he could have meant?

You'll have to ask him. There's no way for us to read his mind.

Answer (score -4):

As per QM, there are three forces that balance out to keep an electron at a stable energy level:

1. the electron's potential EM energy keeps it close to the nucleus
2. the electron's kinetic energy (momentum) keeps it away from the nucleus
3. the HUP keeps it away from the nucleus (in case it should get too close)

> In quantum mechanics, the uncertainty principle (also known as Heisenberg's uncertainty principle) is any of a variety of mathematical inequalities[1] asserting a fundamental limit to the precision with which certain pairs of physical properties of a particle, known as complementary variables or canonically conjugate variables such as position x and momentum p, can be known or, depending on interpretation, to what extent such conjugate properties maintain their approximate meaning, as the mathematical framework of quantum physics does not support the notion of simultaneously well-defined conjugate properties expressed by a single value.

Now the HUP makes sure that there is a very low probability for the electron to exist inside the nucleus (maybe this is what you are referring to).

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100315/discussion-on-answer-by-arpad-szendrei-should-the-ground-state-electron-density).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as posed.

Comment: How does the HUP keep the electron away from the nucleus?

Comment: @AaronStevens when the electron is constrained to a small space (if it would come close to the nucleus because the QM orbital would be too close), its position will be known with high certainty, and thus the HUP, its momentum will be known with less certainty (will rise), moving it away from the nucleus.

Comment: But finding it near (or at) the nucleus does not mean it is constrained there, right?

Comment: The HUP just refers to standard deviations of measurements. If you are talking about the electron being constrained to the nucleus then I agree that you would get a larger $\Delta p$. But that is no longer the energy ground state, which is what is being asked about.

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei The OP itself contains a counter-example which both (i) satisfies the HUP and (ii) has a nonzero probability density at the nucleus. How can you *possibly* claim that the former makes the latter impossible? Why are you (again) sticking to a claim that has been thoroughly disproved in front of you?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty If it is about the ground state (which is in the title) then my answer does not apply. I thought this question was simply about why the electron being (for a long time) really close to the nucleus has low probability.